# error when creating 2d texture with dynamic format

Tags: directx, shader, gpgpu, directx-11, compute-shader

i am pretty newbie on directx.
and i am stumbling with handling resource.

Okay First, i created texture that i can read/write in GPU, and it worked well. 
And now, as you can check in my code, i wanted to read this texture in CPU as well(reading from application side), so i edited the usage from USAGE_DEFAULT to USAGE_DYNAMIC.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> outputTexture;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC outputTex_desc;
outputTex_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
outputTex_desc.Width = 3;
outputTex_desc.Height = 3;
outputTex_desc.MipLevels = 1;
outputTex_desc.ArraySize = 1;
outputTex_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | 
                           D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
outputTex_desc.SampleDesc.Count = msCount;
outputTex_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = msQuality;
outputTex_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
outputTex_desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
outputTex_desc.MiscFlags = 0;

// CREATE 'TEXTURE'
device->CreateTexture2D(      // FAIL HERE !!!
            &outputTex_desc,
            nullptr,
            outputTexture.GetAddressOf());
// CREATE 'SRV'
...
// CREATE 'UAV'
...
```

and it starts failing exactly when it executes the 'device->CreateTexture2D()'

any advice would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two steps in debugging any Direct3D 11 program is:

1. Make sure you are checking every `HRESULT` for either success (`SUCCEEDED` macro) or failure (`FAILED` macro). If it is safe to ignore the return value at runtime, then the function returns `void`. See [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).
2. Enable the Direct3D debug device and look for debug output (a.k.a. use `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` in your Debug configuration).

If you enable the [Direct3D debug device](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/), you'll get detailed information on why the API returns failure codes in many cases.

If you did that, you'd see the error for this code:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: A D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC Resource
may only have the D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE CPUAccessFlags set.
[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #98: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDCPUACCESSFLAGS]
```

In order to *READ* it on the CPU, you must copy to a `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` Resource first. For example source code on doing that, see the [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/ScreenGrab.cpp) code from [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

You don't mention what your `msCount` or `msQuality` values are here. I assumed 1, and 0 respectively. If you use any other values, you'll get:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: Multisampling is not supported
with the D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS BindFlag.  SampleDesc.Count must be 1
and SampleDesc.Quality must be 0.
[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #99: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDBINDFLAGS]
```

Comment: thank chuck. yes i set bindflag '0' and usage to 'staging' and it succeeded !

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a texture from cpu (read mode), you need you create a separate staging texture, then copy your texture into it.

These are the flags for the gpu only texture (please note I force sample count to 1, as UAV access is not allowed for multisampled textures)

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC gpuTexDesc;
gpuTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
gpuTexDesc.Width = 3;
gpuTexDesc.Height = 3;
gpuTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
gpuTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
gpuTexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | 
                       D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
gpuTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
gpuTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
gpuTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
gpuTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_NONE;
gpuTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

Then you create a second texture for reading

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC readTexDesc;
readTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
readTexDesc.Width = 3;
readTexDesc.Height = 3;
readTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
readTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
readTexDesc.BindFlags = 0; //No bind flags allowed for staging
readTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
readTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
readTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING; //need staging flag for read
readTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
readTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

then you can use [CopyResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copyresource):

```
deviceContext->CopyResource(readTex, gpuTex);
```

Once done, you can finally access texture data for reading using [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-map)

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
deviceContext->Map(readTex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &MappedResource);
```

MappedResource will give you access to data in cpu, once you done processing, don't forget to [Unmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-unmap) the resource.

```
deviceContext->Unmap(readTex, 0);
```